# Can 'on error' callback be invoked after success callback has already been called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, econnreset

I am seeing a strange behavior in the code below.

cb1 is called when request req succeeds.
After that cb2 is also called, which doesn't seem right.

```js
var result = {};

// populate options object

var req = https.request(options, function(response) {  // cb1
  callback(null, result);
});

req.on('error', function(err) {     // cb2
  callback(err, result);
});
req.setTimeout(30000); // 5 mins
req.setNoDelay(true);

if (requestBody) {
  req.write(requestBody);
}
req.end();
```

If an https request has already succeeded ( **response.statuscode** was set to 200 in cb1), is it possible for 'on error' handler to be invoked later, on same request object?

The cb2 function is invoked with

> Error: read ECONNRESET

My assumption was this should never happen, hence 'callback' has some code, which if called twice for same incoming request, causes my server to crash.

In addition, I am using the following 2 settings on https module.

```
https.globalAgent.maxSockets = 65000;
https.globalAgent.keepAlive = true;
```

Is it possible that keepAlive setting is somehow keeping the connection to backend server alive, and when the server terminates this connection, cb2 is invoked again on the same req object?

Comment: I don't think keepAlive is involve. Why don't you use `res.on('data', func())` as specified in nodejs doc ? The `https.request` provided function is always triggered even if there was an error.

Comment: @Antoine - I am using `res.on('data', func)` inside `callback(null, result)` call. I did not want to obfuscate my primary question with what I thought was non-relevant code